# How to fix OpenCV Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use openCV to detect red round object and draw a circle around that object. However,the segmentation fault occurs when i use circle function to draw circle. I don't know why is it happening and how to fix it? Thanks!!

```
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <cxcore.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<opencv/cv.h>
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;  // if you don want to use scope resolution operator(::) in the code to call the classes or functions from cv namespace, you need this line
using namespace std; // if you don want to use scope resolution operator(::) in the code to call the classes or functions from std namespace, you need this line


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

VideoCapture capWebcam(0);  //use scope resolution operator :: because VideoCapture is a class under namespace of cv
                                //use VideoCapture class to instantiate an object called capWebcam; here used the constructor of the object immediately to
                                //grab the only (0) camera

if(capWebcam.isOpened()==false){  //check whether the camera is detected and successfully grabbed


    printf("Error: camera not detected!!\n");
    cout<<"Error: camera not detected!!\n"<<endl;
    return(1);
}


    Mat matOriginal;   // matrix object used to store image from webcam
    Mat matProcessed;

    vector<Vec3f> vecCircles;  //declare a 3-element vector of type floats, this will be the pass by reference(i.e. a pointer) output of HoughCicles()

    vector<Vec3f>::iterator itrCircles;  //iterator for circles vector  just a counter, but has the same data type from the itrCircles' data member

    namedWindow("Original"); //window for original image
    namedWindow("Processed"); //window for Processed image

    char charCheckForEscKey =0;

    while(charCheckForEscKey!=27){   //as long as ESC is not pressed, stays in the while

            if(capWebcam.read(matOriginal) == false){   //check to see whether  the image read from webcam correctly

                    cout<<"Error: image frame not read!!\n"<<endl;
                break;
            } //

    inRange(matOriginal,     //this time we don't need to pass a pointer; we pass the image as an object instead
            Scalar(0,0,175),    //specify the lower bound of BGR we want to keep
            Scalar(100,100,256), //upper bound of BGR
            matProcessed);    //return the processed image to another object


    GaussianBlur(matProcessed,matProcessed,Size(9,9),1.5,1.5);  //take matProcessed image and blur by Gaussian filter(9x9 window with std of 1.5 in both x,y direction) and return to same object

    HoughCircles(matProcessed,
                 vecCircles,   //use vector element to receive the x,y,radius of the detected circle
                 CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,  //algorithms used to detect circles
                 2,                   //size of image divided by this value = "accumulator resolution"
                 matProcessed.rows/4,  //min distance between the centers of two detected circles
                 100,       //upper pixel value threshold for canny edge detection to interpret as edge
                 50,        //lower pixel value threshold for canny edge detection to interpret as edge
                 10,        //min radius of a circle can be detected
                 400);      //max radius of a circle can be detected

     for(itrCircles = vecCircles.begin();itrCircles != vecCircles.end();itrCircles++)  //retrieve the x,y and radius of the detected circles from vecCircles object one by one


        cout<< "circle position x = " << (*itrCircles)[0]  //because itrCircles is a pointer(pass by reference), to get the value need to use * to dereference
                            << ",y = " << (*itrCircles)[1]
                            << ",r = " << (*itrCircles)[2] << "\n" << endl;


        // draw the center of detected circle in green
        circle(matOriginal,
               Point((int)(*itrCircles)[0],(int)(*itrCircles)[1]),
               3,
               Scalar(0,255,0),
               CV_FILLED);


        // draw the circumference of detected circle
        circle(matOriginal,
               Point((int)(*itrCircles)[0],(int)(*itrCircles)[1]),
               (int)(*itrCircles)[2],
               Scalar(0,0,255),
               3);


    imshow("Original",matOriginal);  //show the original mat(image)   in Original window
    imshow("Processed",matProcessed);// show the processed mat(image) in Processed window

    charCheckForEscKey = waitKey(10);  // delay 10 ms to allow a time gap to listen to any key pressed

} // end while


 return(0);
} // end main
```

Comment: You start by running in a debugger to locate the crash in your code. When you run in a debugger, the debugger will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack, and also examine the values of variables. If the debugger doesn't stop in your code, walk up the call stack until you reach your code, and there examine the variables involved in the expression causing the crash. At the very least, please narrow down the code in your question to the problematic part, and tell us where the crash happens and variable values.

Comment: did you compile in debug mode and link against release libraries or vice-versa?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!! I am new to OpenCV. I did use debug mode, and it shows the error occurs at the 1st circle function when I want to draw the center of detected circles.  Thanks for Miki fixed my bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by the missing parenthesis on the for loop, and so the iterators you are using to draw are not correctly initialized. You should do:

```
for(itrCircles = vecCircles.begin();itrCircles != vecCircles.end();itrCircles++) 
{
    // your functions
}
```

May I suggest to drop iterators, and use the foreach loop?

```
for (const auto& circ : vecCircles)
{
     // your functions
}
```

Here the full example, cleaned from all useless stuff (especially useless headers).

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace cv;  
using namespace std; 

int main(){

    VideoCapture capWebcam(0); 
    if (capWebcam.isOpened() == false){  
        cout << "Error: camera not detected!!\n" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat matOriginal;   // matrix object used to store image from webcam
    Mat matProcessed;
    vector<Vec3f> vecCircles;  

    namedWindow("Original"); //window for original image
    namedWindow("Processed"); //window for Processed image

    char charCheckForEscKey = 0;
    while (charCheckForEscKey != 27){   //as long as ESC is not pressed, stays in the while

        if (!capWebcam.read(matOriginal)){   
            cout << "Error: image frame not read!!" << endl;
            break;
        } //

        inRange(matOriginal,     //this time we don't need to pass a pointer; we pass the image as an object instead
            Scalar(0, 0, 175),    //specify the lower bound of BGR we want to keep
            Scalar(100, 100, 256), //upper bound of BGR
            matProcessed);    //return the processed image to another object

        GaussianBlur(matProcessed, matProcessed, Size(9, 9), 1.5, 1.5);  //take matProcessed image and blur by Gaussian filter(9x9 window with std of 1.5 in both x,y direction) and return to same object

        HoughCircles(matProcessed,
            vecCircles,   //use vector element to receive the x,y,radius of the detected circle
            CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,  //algorithms used to detect circles
            2,                   //size of image divided by this value = "accumulator resolution"
            matProcessed.rows / 4,  //min distance between the centers of two detected circles
            100,       //upper pixel value threshold for canny edge detection to interpret as edge
            50,        //lower pixel value threshold for canny edge detection to interpret as edge
            10,        //min radius of a circle can be detected
            400);      //max radius of a circle can be detected

        for (const auto& circ : vecCircles)  //retrieve the x,y and radius of the detected circles from vecCircles object one by one
        {
            cout << "circle position x = " << circ[0]  //because itrCircles is a pointer(pass by reference), to get the value need to use * to dereference
                << ",y = " << circ[1]
                << ",r = " << circ[2] << "\n" << endl;

            // draw the center of detected circle in green
            circle(matOriginal, Point(circ[0], circ[1]), 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);

            // draw the circumference of detected circle
            circle(matOriginal, Point(circ[0], circ[1]), circ[2], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
        }

        imshow("Original", matOriginal);  //show the original mat(image)   in Original window
        imshow("Processed", matProcessed);// show the processed mat(image) in Processed window

        charCheckForEscKey = waitKey(10);  // delay 10 ms to allow a time gap to listen to any key pressed

    } // end while

    return(0);
} // end main
```

Comment: Great Thanks!! I am new to OpenCV.